# Not able to return false in equals() method when object o is null. I have added my equals() implementation as well the test case

Tags: java, oop, junit, compilation

My equals() method:
Here when in second if statement when my my object is null for example, I should return false but for some reason my code fails to do so. Any help?

```
public boolean equals(Prof o) {

    boolean res = false;
    
    if(this == o) {
        res = true;
    }
    if(o == null || this.getClass() != o.getClass()) {
        res = false; 
    }
    Prof other = (Prof) o;
    if(this.year == other.year) { 
        if(this.id.equals(other.id)) {
            res = true; 
            }
    }
    else {
        res = false;
    }
    return res;   
}
```

Test Case:

```
public void test02_ProfEqualHash() {

    Prof  p1 = new Prof("John S Lee", "yu213", 5);
     
    assertTrue(p1.equals(p1));
    
    Prof p0 = null; // null
    assertFalse(p1.equals(p0));  // my equals() implementation fails here 
    
    Date d = new Date();
    String s = "Hello";
    assertFalse(p1.equals(d)); 
    assertFalse(p1.equals(s));  
    
    
    Prof  p2 = new Prof("John L", "yu213", 5);  
    assertTrue(p1.equals(p2));
     
    assertTrue(p1.hashCode() == p2.hashCode());
     
    assertTrue(p2.equals(p1)); 
    
    Prof  p3 = new Prof("John S Lee", "yu203", 5); 
    assertFalse(p1.equals(p3));
     
    //assertNotEquals(p1.hashCode(), p3.hashCode());  
    
    Prof  p4 = new Prof("Tracy T", "yu053", 2);
    assertFalse(p1.equals(p4));
    //assertNotEquals(p1.hashCode(), p4.hashCode()); 
    
    Prof  p5 = new Prof("John S Lee", "yu213", 8); 
    assertFalse(p1.equals(p5));
    //assertTrue(p1.hashCode() != p5.hashCode());
    
}
```

Comment: My suggestion: return immediately in the if-condition with the true or false that you have already determined. ``if (o == null) return false;`` The same on the other conditions. Also, the parameter must be ``Object o``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java Object class is the superclass of every class. So in order to override the equal method defined in the Object class, you need to follow the same method definition, which is:

```java
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
   // here goes your implementation class
}
```

Since your definition of `equals` has `Prof` as an argument, hence you are not actually overriding the Object `equals` method.

For more information on the `equals` contract, you can read [`Item10`](https://ahdak.github.io/blog/effective-java-part-2/) from `Effective Java` book by `Josh Bloch`.

Also, if your class has an equals method, then you should always define the hashCode implementation as well. Here is the implementation of this method:

```java
 @Override
 public int hashCode() {
     return Objects.hash(year, id);
 }
```

Comment: I think you are getting an NPE in your test case, since in your implementation other.year will result in NPE because the other is nul.

Comment: I passed that statement. I was able to return false. Thank you!

Comment: my code stops at assertTrue(p1.hashCode() == p2.hashCode()); I am still learning about obligatory methods and have no clue how to pass this hashCode() test case. Any input would be appreciated

Comment: If you read the item10 that  I mentioned in my answer, it says that you should always implement hashcode method as well in your class if you want your object to be comparable. I am guessing that you haven't implemented hasCode method in your class. Also if you are using an IDE like Intellij, then IDE will generate this method for you.

Comment: You are right, I haven't implemented hashCode() in my code. I need some help implementing it as I'm very new to obligatory methods. I will look into item11 now, thanks.

Comment: Well you can remove that part, sure, but I would argue that it would be big plus for this answer when you explain why OPs `equals` was still called in that narrow test case, but won't be in all other cases.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, in order to correctly override `Object`'s `equals()`, the method signature should be:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    ....
}
```

Even though your test code calls your `equals()` method, JDK classes that expect `Object`'s `equals()` signature will not.

In addition, you should return `false` immediately when you find that the `o` argument is `null`, in order not to access it later in your method (which would cause `NullPointerException`).

A correct implementation can look like this:

```
public boolean equals (Object o) 
{
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    }
    if (o == null || !(o instanceof Prof)) {
        return false; 
    }
    Prof other = (Prof) o;
    return this.year == other.year && this.id.equals(other.id);
}
```

Comment: I was able to return false now after making corrections to my code, but my code stops at assertTrue(p1.hashCode() == p2.hashCode()); 
I am still learning about obligatory methods and have no clue how to pass this hashCode() test case. Any input would be appreciated

Comment: @Nzed You should override the `int hashCode()` method. If two objects are equal, they should have the same hashCode. In other words, `hashCode()` should return an `int` that is a function of all the properties you are comparing in `equals()`.